# Horizontally centering a CSS menu

Tags: css, menu, alignment

Going over many articles on how to horizontally center a menu, I just can't seem to kill the beast. Is there anyone that would be able to help with the code:

I probably have already totally garbled it with all my attempts to get it to align. :-)

Thanks!

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="masthead"> </div>
<div id="top-nav" >     
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#"> Europe </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> N. America </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> S. America </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Asia </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Africa </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Australia </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Misc </a></li></ul>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
}
#top-nav {
height: 50px;
background : transparent;
height : 77px;
list-style : none;
margin-top : 7px;
margin-bottom : 11px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
ul.nav {
border-radius: 15px;
background : transparent;
height : 57px;
line-height : 31px;
list-style : none;
padding : 0 10px;
font-size : 14px;
font-weight: bolder;
}
ul.nav li {
display : inline;
padding : 0;
background : transparent;
}
ul.nav a {
font: 100%;
background: transparent;
height : 30px;
font-size : 12px;
color: #000000;
float : left;
padding : 11px 19px 11px 16px;
text-decoration : none;
border-top: 1px solid #252525;
border-bottom : 4px solid #252525;
border-left : 1px solid transparent;
border-right : 1px solid transparent;
border-radius : 4px;
-moz-border-radius : 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}
ul.nav a:hover {
background : #252525;
border-top : 1px solid #252525;
border-bottom : 4px solid #000;
border-left : 1px solid #252525;
border-right : 1px solid #252525;
color : #FFF;
padding : 11px 19px 11px 16px;
border-radius : 4px;
-moz-border-radius : 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: If you are ok with new css, use `display: inline-block;` on li elements than `text-align: center;` on ul, this will center everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want? **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LXMfE/6/)**

Just add this CSS rules to the `#top-nav` element:

```
text-align: center;
```

And this to the `ul.nav` element:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: Geez, I really thought I had already tried that a few times, but it starts to align. Thanks for your quick answer :-)

Comment: No problem, if I've helped you, you can help me marking this question as the correct answer.

Comment: one more question. I'm using expression web 4. I now see that the ul.nav has a 10-15px area in front of it, that is marked in diagonal red stripes. This keeps it from aligning perfectly. Any thoughts what that could be?